# How is it possible to write a struct into a file?

Tags: c, struct

I would like to write a struct into a binary file.

My struct looks like this:

```
struct {
    int a;
    int b;

    struct c {
        int d;
        int e;
    };
};
```

is there any function, to write an instance of this structure into a file? If not, then how should I do it?

Comment: `fwrite()` if you're using file streams; `write()` if you're using file descriptors.  And it only works reliably if you're going to read it back on the same sort of machine as you write it on.  If you need cross-platform portability, you have to work harder. It also works because you don't have any pointers in your structure. If you have pointers, you have a bigger set of problems to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no automated way in C to read/write structures to a file. You're going to have to create your own formatting and parsing routines. Basically calls to sprintf/write and read/sscanf with the appropriate formatting strings. If you can switch to C++ then check out JSON or XML libraries.

The technical term for saving and loading objects and structures to/from storage is Serialization.